# Positioning elements next to each other without float don't line up at top correctly

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to position multiple `divs` next to each other using `inline-flex`, however they're not lining up on top (see screenshot). If I remove the `svg` however, the `divs` line up correctly. ‍♂️ It also works if I use the `float: right` or a negative `margin-top` property but I want to avoid that because it's not intended for this and a bit hacky.

[image: Link to screenshot]

My code is:

```css
 .wrapper {
      height: 100%;
    }

    .item,
    form,
    .input-container {
      height: 100%;
      display: inline-flex;
      align-items: center;
    }

    button {
      border: none;
      background: #111;
      height: 100%;
      width: 16px;
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .icon {
      height: 16px;
      width: auto;
      float: left;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
   <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="item">
        <!-- Search form with svg image -->
        <form>
          <button class="k-submit" for="search" id="k-submit" type="submit" aria-label="Open searchbox">
            <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 55 55">
              <path d="M54.1 49.8L40 35.7c2.8-3.6 4.4-8.2 4.4-13.1 0-12-9.7-21.7-21.7-21.7S.9 10.6.9 22.6s9.7 21.7 21.7 21.7c4.9 0 9.5-1.6 13.1-4.4L49.9 54l4.2-4.2zM6.9 22.6c0-8.7 7.1-15.7 15.7-15.7 8.7 0 15.7 7.1 15.7 15.7 0 8.7-7.1 15.7-15.7 15.7s-15.7-7-15.7-15.7z" fill="#111"></path>
            </svg>
          </button>
          <div class="input-container">
            <!-- Search input field -->
            <input value="Suche" type="search">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">
          English
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
```

I edited the screenshot for better view of the containers. It's actually the containers which are not lining up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vertical align inline-flex elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281226/vertical-align-inline-flex-elements)

Comment: Hi, no, I'm already using `align-items: center` Thx though!

Comment: **EDIT:** I edited the screenshot for better view of the containers. It's actually the containers which are not lining up.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bnzjo5tk/1/  is this what you want?

Comment: If you want 'align-items: center' to work on all three elements, they must be in the same flexbox.  I would suggest adding 'display: flex' and 'align-items: center' to your .wrapper div. Your other divs could just be block level.

Answer (score 0):

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.item,
form,
.input-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: #111;
  height: 100%;
  width: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  height: 16px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
.top{
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <!-- Search form with svg image -->
    <form>
      <button class="k-submit" for="search" id="k-submit" type="submit" aria-label="Open searchbox">
        <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 55 55">
          <path d="M54.1 49.8L40 35.7c2.8-3.6 4.4-8.2 4.4-13.1 0-12-9.7-21.7-21.7-21.7S.9 10.6.9 22.6s9.7 21.7 21.7 21.7c4.9 0 9.5-1.6 13.1-4.4L49.9 54l4.2-4.2zM6.9 22.6c0-8.7 7.1-15.7 15.7-15.7 8.7 0 15.7 7.1 15.7 15.7 0 8.7-7.1 15.7-15.7 15.7s-15.7-7-15.7-15.7z" fill="#111"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="input-container">
        <!-- Search input field -->
        <input value="Suche" type="search">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="item top">
    <a href="http://www.example.com">
      English
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution:

Move your `div` with `class='item'` into the same parent `div` that your `form` is in.

It lined up automatically for me doing that. As you mentioned, the containers weren't lining up and that's because they didn't belong in the same parent `div`.

The *slight* difference you might see in my solution could be due to the way the browser renders the underline under the `a` tag for "English". That underline makes it look even lower than it is lol. If you use `text-decoration: none;` on your `a` tag, it'll line up perfectly.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100%;
}

.item,
form,
.input-container {
  height: 100%;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  border: none;
  background: #111;
  height: 100%;
  width: 16px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.icon {
  height: 16px;
  width: auto;
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="item">
      <!-- Search form with svg image -->
      <form>
        <button class="k-submit" for="search" id="k-submit" type="submit" aria-label="Open searchbox">
          <svg class="icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 55 55">
            <path
              d="M54.1 49.8L40 35.7c2.8-3.6 4.4-8.2 4.4-13.1 0-12-9.7-21.7-21.7-21.7S.9 10.6.9 22.6s9.7 21.7 21.7 21.7c4.9 0 9.5-1.6 13.1-4.4L49.9 54l4.2-4.2zM6.9 22.6c0-8.7 7.1-15.7 15.7-15.7 8.7 0 15.7 7.1 15.7 15.7 0 8.7-7.1 15.7-15.7 15.7s-15.7-7-15.7-15.7z"
              fill="#111"></path>
          </svg>
        </button>
        <div class="input-container">
          <!-- Search input field -->
          <input value="Suche" type="search">
        </div>
      </form>
      <div class="item">
        <a href="http://www.example.com">
          English
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want element by lining up on top. Please use "align-items: inherit;" instead of that center. Example is:-

```
.item, form, .input-container {
height: 100%;
display: inline-flex;
align-items: inherit;}
```